# Yeast overdose?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, cider, fruit

So I'm new to the home-brewing scene, and I was a bit too excited to get started with my apple cider. I misread the instructions, and instead of using half a teaspoon for a 2lt bottle of juice.. I used an entire packet :/

Will it taste like satan's piss? Is there any salvation to it? I'm using Lalvin EC-1118 Champagne yeast.

I still have about 1 gallon of juice, and an extra cap/airlock. Should I mix it / dilute it with the rest of the juice.. or just chuck it and make a new round? Or just let it be and it will turn out ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be fine.  Relax, don't worry, have ... some cider?

Comment: That's great news! I was just a bit worried about having put about 10x the amount of yeast than I was supposed to. Will this affect fermention time? I don't want it to be too strong, so I was planning on letting it ferment for a week. Would the extra yeast accelerate this?

Comment: The packets of EC-1118 I've had are, I would guess, about 1 teaspoon.  If you used one of those, it doesn't seem like much, event for a small amount of juice like 2 liters.  You'll soon know how it turned out, but I wouldn't do anything to try to "fix" it now.  I'm not sure how you're planning to package it, but normally you have to let something ferment until it is done, rather than an arbitrary time period like "a week".

Comment: well that's good to know  :). Well what I wanted was to stop fermentation before ALL of the sugar is consumed, so it still tastes a bit sweet. I'm using a glass jug with an airtight lid, so after a week or so, I was planning on taking out the airlock and put the lid on.. let it carbonate for a few days and then enjoy :P

Comment: You can't stop fermentation by putting a lid on the jug.  That would just (potentially) explode the jug.  But if you just let it go a few days after putting the lid on you might be okay.

Comment: Will it stop if I put the jug in the fridge? I was thinking of putting the lid, let it keep fermenting for a couple of days, and put it in the fridge